# Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in netbeans

Tags: php, sqlite, netbeans

I want to do connectivity between SQLite and PHP in NetBeans. I have successfully created database in SQLite and Connectivity is also done successfully. Now I want to execute simple query so i have written following code. but it showing

**Fatal error**: `Class 'SQLite3' not found in C:\Users\Akshay\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Sample\index.php on line 15`

```
<?php
/**
* Simple example of extending the SQLite3 class and changing the __construct
* parameters, then using the open method to initialize the DB.
*/
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
function __construct()
{
$this->open('C:\\SQLITE\\TravelMate.db');
}
}
$db = new MyDB();
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM admin');
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use relative path?

Comment: can you plz elaborate it. i'm new to this stuff.... plz.

Comment: relative path means path from your project folder